# Ninja-edit if your comment/answer is less than one minute old

Tags: feature-request, comments, edits

If your comment is less than one minute old *at the time you click submit* (meaning, not when you click the edit button) the little pencil will not come up: [image]

This is because if your comment is less than one minute old the most likely reason you are editing it is to fix a grammatical error. Good idea?

Comment: Does it really matter? I don't really see a benefit.

Comment: It's a small idea but (in my opinion) that pencil is really annoying. And I'm not sure if you're kidding or not by editing it in under a minute, can you fill me in?

Comment: Well, I don't find it to be very annoying and the chances for abuse are not so trivial (someone would *certainly* use this to troll).

Comment: How would you use it to troll?

Comment: @chipperyman573: Who knows?

Comment: Not me, that's for sure.

Comment: This was already suggested before... and declined.

Answer (score 4):

As a non-native speaker I must say one minute is damn short to really fix your grammar. Allowed 5 minutes for comment edit now once in a while are to short. Thus making it long enough to fix grammar for us with English as second or third language would really mean removing pencil icon from comments altogether.

Answer (score 1):

If you spot a grammatical error in the first minute of your comment's life, spending some seconds proofreading before hitting the add comment button would solve this problem.